# prediction for loess() function

Tags: r, regression, prediction, predict, loess

I`m trying to predict only two values, the model is

```
data(mtcars) #is already available in R

m1 = loess(mtcars$mpg ~ mtcars$cyl + mtcars$disp)
# the prdedict function works well
y.predict <- predict(m1, data.frame(mtcars$cyl, mtcars$disp))
```

but it estimates the model m1 by using all the exists values of the two predictors

mtcars$cyl and mtcars$disp, and I want estimate just one value of mtcars$mpg.

I tried

```
new.data= data.frame(mtcars$cyl=c(2,3), mtcars$disp=c(200,1000))
y.predict <- predict(m1, new.data)
```

But it gives me the following 
Warning message:
'newdata' had 2 rows but variables found have 32 rows

Appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

It's a nuance in the notation, try it this way:

```
data(mtcars) #is already available in R
attach(mtcars) # attach it to the environment so you can use column names directly
m1 = loess(mpg ~ cyl + disp)
# the prdedict function works well
y.predict <- predict(m1, data.frame(cyl, disp))

# add new data
new.data = data.frame(cyl = c(6,8), disp = c(150,100))
y.predict <- predict(m1, new.data)
```